# Python script using Tweepy stops for no reason

Tags: logging, twitter, tweepy, python-logging

I have a list of screen names (a few hundred) and their tweets (the ids). With that list, I'm using Twitter API to get the tweet status and the retweeters' ids. I'm using the code I show below that works fine.

The problem is that after a few screen names (10-15) from the initial list, the python script stops without printing any error. Initially, I was running the script with:

```
python get_rt.py > log 2>&1 &
```

which sometimes does not "catch" all the print errors. So I implemented a traceback with logging and there is no error in the traceback. The script justs stop for some reason.

Any idea why it stops or how should I do to catch the error?

```
import io,json,sys
import traceback
import logging

#Logging
LOG_FILENAME = 'log_exception.txt'
logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILENAME, level=logging.DEBUG)


# Tweepy
import tweepy,time
consumer_key = 'XXX'
consumer_secret = 'XXX'
auth = tweepy.AppAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True, compression=True)

#MongoDB
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27018)
db = client['Twitter']
col_tweets = db['Tweets']
col_users = db['Users']

#Usefull function to save data to DB
def save_user(user_info):
    id_str = user_info['id_str']
    col_users.update({'id_str':id_str},user_info,upsert = True)
def save_tweet(tweet_info):
    id_str = tweet_info['id_str']
    col_tweets.update({'id_str':id_str},tweet_info,upsert = True)


screen_names = [...] #list of screen names
try:

    for sc_name in screen_names:
        print(sc_name)
        tweets_data = []
        with io.open('tweets_{}.json'.format(sc_name)) as f: #open the file containing the tweets from screen names X
            for line in f:
                tweet = json.loads(line)
                if tweet['retweets_count'] >= 1:
                    tweets_data.append(tweet)
        if not tweets_data:
            continue

        for i,tweet in enumerate(tweets_data):
            t_id = tweet['id']
            try:
                rts = api.retweets(id = t_id,count = 100,tweet_mode="extended")
                if rts:
                    retweeted_status = rts[0]._json['retweeted_status']
                    rts_u_ids = []
                    for rt in rts:
                        rt = rt._json
                        user_rt = rt['user']
                        save_user(user_rt)
                        rts_u_ids.append(user_rt['id_str'])
                    retweeted_status['retweeters_ids'] = rts_u_ids
                    save_tweet(retweeted_status)
            except tweepy.TweepError:
                time.sleep(60 * 15)
                print("Sleeping 60*15")
except Exception as e:
    logging.error(traceback.format_exc())
```